# Gatsby CLI Won't Install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to install the Gatsby CLI, but I run into this error every time.

[shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfhs.png)

I'm on a Mac, and I am using the sudo command. `sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli` is what's getting me here. Since I'm using `sudo`, I don't understand why there's a permissions problem.

Any recommendations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli --unsafe-perm`

Comment: @Raymond Just tried it. It seems like it installed, but the `gatsby` command isn't found. It also installed two deprecated modules.

Comment: First answer I had was the gatsby module not the command line global module. For the command line Gatsby use: `sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli --unsafe-perm`

Comment: @Raymond That got it working! Thanks for the help. If you have time, can you explain what's going on here? Thanks again!

Comment: where is the $PATH